MII to SGMII to connect ETH Switch is it possible?
I want to connect MCU with parallel MII interfaces to  switch ICs with SGMII interfaces in this method :

The Eth SW support 8xMDI Channel and 4xSERDES(SGMII,USXGMII,5GBASE-X , ETC).
I'm afraid that I missing some point after I read the datasheet of MAX24287, the connection to the  ETH SW required some term called "MAC".
please see the Application Examples from datasheet(MAX24287 PAGE 6):

what is the meaning of the term MAC and what do I need to ensure in my ETH SW? maybe the connection isn't possible in this architecture? maybe the MAC isn't available after I using 8xMDI Ports?

MAC stands for Media Access Control and it is the controller that allows a device to interact with a physical layer ethernet device (PHY)

STM32F4 datasheet
You need to match the MII to something that is MII which you have done with the MAX24287, which on the other end of the MAX24287 is SGMII which needs to connect to something that is SGMII. So the switch needs to support SGMII for this connection to work.
On the switch side, you have multiple MAC's that talk to the Layer 2 switch hardware and handle the SGMII packets, then hand them off to the switch to move them to the appropriate port.

Please see the attaching diagram, they used MAC in Ethernet switch, what they meaning? The Mac in the side of uC understandable.

Same thing, you need a MAC on the switch side before it can talk to Level 2 stuff, it needs to construct the packet back from serial, and then hand it off to the switch controller. So the Switch has a MAC for each port.

Ok, do I need to check with Switch if they have MAC on his Serdes port? Or it obviously?

If it uses SGMII then you should be fine, just need to match the interface.
